# Drupal - How to check if on admin page?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I use the following code in my **page.tpl.php** of a Drupal 7 installation:

```
if (!path_is_admin(current_path())) {
    $pathArray = explode('/', current_path());
    if (!empty($pathArray)) {
        $path_to_node = url("node/".$pathArray[1]);
        $menuChildArray = explode('/', $path_to_node);
        $menuParent = $menuChildArray[2];
    }
}
```

But on some pages in the admin interface, I get:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in include() (line 36 of /home/www/doc/7622/s-d-d.de/testkc/sites/all/themes/sdd2015/page.tpl.php).

The code should only be executed if I am on the frontend...? Why does it get fired in the backend?

Comment: What do you need exactly? Do you want to find out what page you are on?

Comment: No the above code should only be executed if I am on the frontend ...

Comment: are you looking for whether you logged into admin or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess:

The message is in fact generated when you visit a page on the front end, but because you have this code in page.tpl.php (where it shouldn't be), it can't be printed in the messages area until the *next* page view, as the messages for the current page having already been printed in the same file.

So your code is probably working as expected, but you're seeing a delay on the notice messages being output.

As always, the solution is to check your vars before using them.

```
// Or whatever conditional makes sense to what you're trying to do.
if (!empty($menuChildArray[2])) {
  $menuParent = $menuChildArray[2];
}
```

Comment: Hey Clive, when you say they should not be in page.tpl.php - where should I place the code for the front end then?

Comment: A [preprocess hook](https://www.drupal.org/node/223430) would be the best place @Torben